# Jenkins run-time input get for bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

### jenkins interact with script input at runtime

In my bash script i used read command to get the user input to proceed or abort the script. so far i don't have problem with my script when i use through linux machine.
but when i try to do this in jenkins im not able to get the run time option.
could somebody help me to resolve.

```
my bash output,
A = 10
B = 20
Sum of A + B is : 30
IF SUM value is greater than 25, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'
Do you want to continue (y/n)? : n
```

Comment: Jenkins is supposed to run unattended so I'm not even sure it opens stdin. You need to modify your script to accept the input as arguments

Comment: try to pass yes like `yes | ./my_programm_or_script -args`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but im not able to give at run time, when i get summary for this info "IF SUM value is greater than 25, then press 'n' otherwise, press 'y'" i need to take the discussion  at the run time whether Yes or No, without knowing the verification i won't do.